# return object of getContext

Tags: android, onclick, android-context

When I did the `view.getContext` from `onClick(View view)`, I observed that not always it gives the host activity object.

So,when does `view.getContext()` from `onClick(View view)` returns `ContextThemeWrapper` object or when it returns host activity object or any other object?

Comment: does it really matter what `Context` implementation is returned? what do you want to use it for?

Comment: Yes, as per my requirements, I want to use only host activity in onClick method.

Comment: so you cannot do that or change your requirements... btw why it really matter what Context you get? what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I cannot change my requirements, I want to call host activities method from this onClick method. Also I want to know reason why it sometimes gives ContextThemeWrapper object and sometimes host activities.

Comment: no no no, all you have to do is to create some interface that your activity will implement and use that interface inside onClick callback

Comment: Ok..thank you for that. But, my main goal here is understanding the reason behind the return type of getContext() that is either ContextThemeWrapper or Host Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Context is an interface to global information about an application environment.

Activity class extends ContextThemeWrapper, if you want your activity as a parameter, you need to cast the context to your activity or create your Interface between your components.

If you want to know why, you need to read the source code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java

At line 758:

```
if (themeResId != 0) {
     context = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeResId);
}
```

And at line 908:

```
if (hasThemeOverride) {
        context = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeResId);
}
```

So... if you want to pass your activity as parameter, you shouldn't use context.

Comment: But it does not explains why it sometimes gives ContextThemeWrapper object and sometimes Host activities object.

Comment: No I have not seen yet, please tell me if you know something

Comment: @pskink I have seen the link. But did not seen the source code. If you  have seen the source code and found something, please tell me.